# StackOverflowError while reading file from reactive GridFS

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, mongodb-java

I have a problem with the ReactiveGridFsTemplate. I am trying to read a GridFS file written with the old GridFS (com.mongodb.gridfs) instead of the new GridFS (com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFS) with an UUID as an ID instead of the ObjectId. Reading the GridFS file metainfo goes fine, but as soon as I want to get the ReactiveGridFsResource it blows with a nice new MongoGridFSException("Custom id type used for this GridFS file").

The culprit is the code below from ReactiveGridFsTemplate which calls the getObjectId() instead of the getId(). Should it call this method or can that be rewritten to the getId() method?

```
    public Mono<ReactiveGridFsResource> getResource(GridFSFile file) {
        Assert.notNull(file, "GridFSFile must not be null!");
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            GridFSDownloadStream stream = this.getGridFs().openDownloadStream(file.getObjectId());
            return new ReactiveGridFsResource(file, BinaryStreamAdapters.toPublisher(stream, this.dataBufferFactory));
        });
    }
```

I hacked the ReactiveGridFsTemplate to use getId() instead of getObjectId() but now it gives me a stackoverflow exception. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
        ReactiveGridFsTemplate reactiveGridFsTemplate = new ReactiveGridFsTemplate(mongoDbDFactory, operations.getConverter(), "nl.loxia.collectie.buitenlandbladen.dgn", 1024) {
            public Mono<ReactiveGridFsResource> getResource(GridFSFile file) {
                Assert.notNull(file, "GridFSFile must not be null!");
                return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                    GridFSDownloadStream stream = this.getGridFs().openDownloadStream(file.getId());
                    return new ReactiveGridFsResource(file, BinaryStreamAdapters.toPublisher(stream, this.dataBufferFactory));
                });
            }            
        };

        var q = Query.query((Criteria.where("_id").is("5449d9e3-7f6d-47b7-957d-056842f190f7")));

        List<DataBuffer> block = reactiveGridFsTemplate
                .findOne(q)
                .flatMap(reactiveGridFsTemplate::getResource)
                .flux()
                .flatMap(ReactiveGridFsResource::getDownloadStream)
                .collectList()
                .block();
```

The stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/nickstolwijk/fa77681572db1d91941d85f6c845f2f4

Also, this code hangs due to the stackoverflow exception. Is that correct?

Comment: How can I reproduce that issue? How big is the file you're trying to retrieve? Can you file an issue for `getObjectId` vs. `getId` at https://jira.spring.io?

Comment: Created an issue and a PR for the first problem. I will continue to provide a testcase for the second problem.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2392

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/796

Comment: Created an issue for reading of large files. It seems it has nothing to do with the old gridfs. The tests in spring data mongodb tests with a 1 kb file. When I use a 32k byte[] it succeeds but bigger (48k) fails.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2393

Comment: Thanks a lot. We need to have a look.